how to pass data using usePage from child component to parent component in laravel inertia.js
I've been trying to pass the existing data from child component to parent component, but none of the data showed up. The data already showing up if I directly accessing child route
here is my code
export default function Children({ posts }) {
    
    return (
         
            <>
                <h1>My Super Blog</h1>
                
                <hr/>
                { posts && posts.map( (item) => (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <h2 className="">{item.title}</h2>
                        <p>{item.body}</p>
                    </div>
                )) }
            </>
        
    );
}

import { Link, Head, usePage } from '@inertiajs/react';
import Children from './Index';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Parent({ auth, laravelVersion, phpVersion }) {
    
    const { posts } = usePage().props;

    return (
        <>
            <Head title="Welcome" />
            <div>
                <div>
                    <Children posts={posts} />
                </div>
                
                
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

any help be appreciated, thank you.

figured out, i ended up using axios to fetch the data
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/api/post')  // Replace with your backend endpoint
      .then(response => {
        setPosts(response.data);
        chooseData(response.data);  // Send data to parent component
      });
  }, [chooseData]);

